# Car headlights flickering

Tags: toyota, headlight, hybrid

I got a Toyota Auris hybrid, about 5 years old. The headlights are flickering sometimes. I can not seem to connect it to a certain moment. I have encountered it when driving 80km/h on the engine, but also when driving ~20km/h on the batteries. Usually I spot it when driving on smooth roads, so I don't think it is caused by bumpy roads or loose connections.

It does not happen all the time, usually it performs regular, but sometimes it flickers for like 5 minutes, and then its fine again. It used to be only the right headlight but recently it is happening to both as well. Sometimes it's like driving with a stroboscope in front of my car.

I want to know if I could do something about it, I went to the garage already but they could not find a problem. I was thinking that maybe the battery is getting old and can not keep up with the demanded power usage of the car, and the headlights are the first to give in? Will replacing the battery fix this problem?

Comment: Unlikely to be the battery here - far more likely this is an issue with the wiring. Could be as simple as a loose connection.

Comment: If the Auris runs like the Prius, it has a 12vdc battery which runs the accessories like the lights. This would mean right off the bat it's not the battery (well, the high voltage battery, at least). I agree with @motosubatsu ... it's most likely in the wiring somewhere.

Comment: This wiring problem, would that be the connection of the wire being loose or rusted; or can it also be that there is a breach or rust somewhere in the middle of the cable? @motosubatsu

Comment: connection points are probably the most likely but corrosion or fraying or a break is possible along essentially the entire length - part of what makes tracking down electrical (especially *intermittent* electrical problems) such a time-consuming pain to do :(

Comment: What type of bulbs are installed in the headlights?

Comment: @HandyHowie The bulbs are LED, the exact version and/or brand I'd have to look up, which I can do in around 6 hours

Answer (score 1):

If the bulbs are LED as you say -

> The bulbs are LED, the exact version and/or brand I'd have to look up

then I would first try a new bulb.  LEDs are know to flicker when at the end of life.